Probability Question. Please explain the approach to this question.
You have all 13 clubs. The "value" of a card is the number on the card, where face cards have value 0 and the ace has value 1. You can pay 1 dollar to reveal the difference between any two cards you choose (where order matters). In the end, you choose 2 of the 13 cards and get paid the product of their values. What is the maximum guaranteed profit you can achieve?

I am confused by the posting.  I am guessing that you start out by choosing two cards that are currently face down.  After paying 1 dollar, you see the (?? absolute value ??) of the difference of these two cards.  ..."where order matters" : what does this signify in this context?  In the end you chose 2 of the 13 cards -- so if you choose the 8 and 9, you are guaranteed to receive 72?  This is all very confusing.  Please edit the posted question, striving to make it impossible for anyone to be confused what you are asking.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

@user2661923 I am not very sure myself, I was presented this question in a contest. So these are the exact wordings of the same

Was the question presented in English, or is it possible that you have mistranslated the question from another language?

Also, re the protocol article, how can you discuss solving strategies, or show work, if you can't nail down the exact specifications of the problem?  Perhaps you should consider temporarily deleting the problem so that you can resolve any ambiguity, and then re-post.  Please also consider the linked protocol article, to ensure that the (edited) posting is received positively, at MathSE.
